# OpenCV imread(filename) fails in debug mode when using release libraries

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, libraries

I have some **C++** code and everything was working fine with **OpenCV** except the function `imread(file)`. It was finding correctly the file and loading the name, but it wasn't loading any data.

```
Mat pattImage = imread(fileName, 0);
```

After some reaserch on the web I realized that I was in debug mode but with the release **OpenCV** libraries, instead of the debug ones.

```
debug library:    opencv_core231d.lib
release library:  opencv_core231.lib
```

Though it is the tipical stupid error I thought this shouldn't have anything to do, the debug libraries are supposed to allow **OpenCV** code debugging while the release libraries allow faster execution of the code, but I don't understand why imread was failing.

Can anybody explain me the differences between *debug* and *release* libraries in **OpenCV** and why this error occurs?

Is it an **OpenCV** bug?

Comment: Yes it is 2.3.1. On windows 7, 32bit

Comment: I'll never get tired of telling people that OpenCV for Windows has the wierdest bugs (when you use the C++ interface). Do yourself a favour and write a small test using the C interface to check if it works or not (`cvLoadImage()`, etc).

Comment: Yes with C interface it does work, but I still would like to why it fails, cause I think it shouldn't fail. Maybe in future versions they fix it. Anyway, I still like fixing opencv prblems...

Comment: Reproduced in 2.4.8 version. Something really weird... O_o With debug libraries worked fine.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'll never get tired of telling people that **the C++ OpenCV interface for Windows has the wierdest bugs**.

Write a small test using the C interface to check if it works or not (`cvLoadImage()`, etc).

**Update**: now that you know that the C interface works properly, you can either go to the mailing list and report this bug there or dig into the code yourself to find why it fails.

Comment: In another question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/19206627/575530) I was steered towards the C++ interface instead of the C one, but your answer has me wondering. Would you recommend the C over the C++ interface for Windows users?

Comment: No. The C++ interface is fine. The problem is that some OpenCV installers provide binaries that were compiled with specific flags and you need to set those in your project to be able to build applications with OpenCV. For instance, on Visual Studio, you might want to go to the **Project Properties**, select **C/C++** > **Code Generation**, and make sure the **Runtime Library** field is set to **"Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)"**.

Comment: How do you know if your libraries are mismatched?  I have rebuild opencv with the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG.  I am compiling my test program in eclipse on linux.  But imread loads not valid images.

Comment: The problems reported here does not apply to Linux. Are you passing  the full path to the file (instead of a relative path)?

Answer (score 9):

In  release mode you must use release libraries, in debug mode - debug libraries. It is no bug.

Comment: How exactly do you do that?

Answer (score 3):

Had this problem using Qt (Qt Creator), linking the debug version of the respective library fixed it. This can be done automatically in the project configuration file (.pro):

[QTCreator .pro file: Setting LIBS path depending on DEBUG / RELEASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611399/qtcreator-pro-file-setting-libs-path-depending-on-debug-release)

Answer (score 2):

In general it is perfecly legal to link "Debug" executable configuration against "Release" configuration library (why should not be as far as the symbols exported by the libraries are the same in Debug and in Release?). Unless (for some reasons) you don't want that "mixing" happen.
It turns out that opencv developers decided to not allow such mixing and they perform such probihibition with a specific portion of code (something you can find in the file cvdef.h on release 3.4.4 line 54). 
That is not a C++ interface bug, but a "wanted" behaviour.
You can find more information at https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/9161 where this change has been documented.

Answer (score 1):

Use FORWARD slash (/), instead of a backward slash (). Even in Windows!

**Incorrect:**

```
cv::imread("C:\example\1.jpg");
```

**Correct:**

```
cv::imread("C:/example/1.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

For example OpenCV 4.2,

Change project properties as follows:

Configuration : Debug

Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies

Add opencv_world420**d**.lib

Configuration : Release

Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies

Add opencv_world420.lib

Then you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this issue by changing the runtime library of your Debug application from /MDd (multi-threaded DLL *debug*) to /MD (regular, release version of the multi-threaded DLL runtime).

Your code will still be unoptimized and easier to debug than a normal release mode, but you will lose some debugging information (for example for crashes within the C runtime).  You also lose some debugging features like the debug heap, but if you don't know what that is then it won't affect you.

To do this work around, just go to Properties>C/C++/Code Generation and change "Runtime Library" from /MDd to /MD.