# QTCreator .pro file: Setting LIBS path depending on DEBUG / RELEASE

Tags: build, qt-creator, libs

As a newbie to Qt I am writing a small project depending on another project, located in a parallel directory.

In my `.pro` file some `.obj` files are includes as below (which works). However, when creating a release I'd like to use the other project's release and not its debug path. I have checked the [Qt variables](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html) and found the "TARGET example". But I failed to apply it to my `LIBS`, especially since the build can be for both `debug_and_release` , and I have no idea how to write the `LIBS` path then.

Pro file:

```
LIBS += -L"../../OtherApp/OtherApp-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MSVC2010__Qt_SDK__Debug/debug"
LIBS += http.obj some other obj files
```

"Target example":

```
 build_pass:CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
 unix: TARGET = $$join(TARGET,,,_debug)
 else: TARGET = $$join(TARGET,,,d)
 }
```

Can I write `LIBS += -L"......."$$(TARGET)"......"` , especially if target may contain both debug and release?

[Edit 1]
I have found a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11612903/356726

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the wizard (inlucde internal library) I got the following "code" created. This is most likely the solution:

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -LLIBS += -L"../../MyApp/current/MyApp-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MSVC2010__Qt_SDK__Release/release"
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L"../../MyApp/current/MyApp-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MSVC2010__Qt_SDK__Debug/debug"
```