# CascadeClassifier::load function always returns false

Tags: opencv

My `CascadeClassifier::load` function returns false even with an absolute path to the xml file :

```
face_cascade.load( "D:/tmp/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml" );
```

I'm using opencv 2.4.5.

Comment: Do you have permissions to open the file?

Comment: @perfanoff ~> yes. I can load it in another projects !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are linking with right libraries: if you compile in Debug configuration, you need to add `opencv_*245d.lib`, but not `opencv_*245.lib`.

`CascadeClassifier::load` is not the only function causing such troubles, see [OpenCV imread(filename) fails in debug mode when using release libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125817/opencv-imreadfilename-fails-in-debug-mode-when-using-release-libraries) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i had the same problems in opencv 2.4.9 and VS 2012

i checked for the right libs for debug, and everithing seems ok, but it didn't worked out.
So the workaround for me is currently, to seperatly atach a debuger in a new VS enviroment.
so that i start my exe from the directory, and then atach a debuger to the process.
i don't know why, but this way it works fine. (xml loads fine)

maybe i should also mention that that the function is originaly called in a DLL.
I use this exe just to test/Debug the DLL.

i hope this helps

~NetForc3