# const float union ptr in Bradski & Kaehler's "Learning OpenCV" Example 3-9

Tags: c, opencv

In "[Learning OpenCV](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516130.do)" by Gary Bradski & Adrian Kaehler there is a section on the CvMat matrix structure that contains the following example code (it is Example 3-9: Summing all the elements in a single-channel matrix)

```
float sum( const CvMat* mat ) { 

  float s = 0.0f;
  for(int row=0; row<mat->rows; row++ ) {
    const float* ptr = (const float *)(mat->data.ptr + row * mat->step);
    for(int col=0; col<mat->cols; col++ ) {
      s += *ptr++;
    }
  }
  return( s );
}
```

There are a couple of things I do not understand about this code, but they may be the result of me not using C for many many years rather than OpenCV questions.

1. Why `const`? Since `ptr` is incremented later in the function I do not understand why it is declared `const`.
2. Why `.ptr`? The authors point out that "When computing the pointer into the matrix, remember that the matrix element `data` is a union. Therefore, when de-referencing this pointer, you must indicate the correct element of the union in order to obtain the correct pointer type." So why not use the union member `fl` with type `float*` so that the line of code would be

   ```
   float* ptr = mat->data.fl + row * mat->step;
   ```

instead of taking `ptr` with type `uchar*` and requiring an additional cast?

Comment: nice book, but you probably should not use the deprecated c-api anymore

Comment: Arghhhhhhh - the API used in the standard text is deprecated?

Comment: well, yes. use he c++ api instead. again, nice book, but please take the code samples from [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/2.4/samples/cpp)

Comment: Good resource, but they don't include the book sample in the question, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why const? Since ptr is incremented later in the function I do not understand why it is declared const.

Because it's not the pointer that's `const` but the object it points to. What you are talking about would be written as `float *const ptr`, but as you can see, `ptr` isn't declared as such.

> Why .ptr?

Because the union may not have the same size as a `float`. Imagine this array:

```
               union *          union *           union *         union *
                 +0               +1               +2               +3 (correct)
                  +----------------+----------------+----------------+
union boundaries: |     union      |     union      |     union      |
                  +----------------+----------------+----------------+
float boundaries: |   float   |junk|   float   |junk|  float    |junk|
                  +----------------+----------------+----------------+
                  ^           ^           ^          ^         ^
               float *     float *     float *    float *    float *
                +0           +1          +2         +3         +4
                           ^--------- these are all wrong ----------^
```

If you get a pointer to the first `float` and apply pointer arithmetic on it, it will produce incorrect results if the `union` is bigger than the `float`.

Comment: Thanks - great answers to both my questions. Given your point about the size of the union when would the `data.fl` union member ever prove useful or safe to use?