# Imread() doesn't work but cvLoadImage() does

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I can't seem to use imread() and my friend suggest a workaround using cvLoadImage(), do anybody know why??? I don't really want to use a workaround.

Comment: you *can* or you *can't* use imread() ?

Comment: most ppl who could not use imread, but cvLoadImage had their libs wrong, 32/64bit debug/release vs version etc.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the spelling error. What do you mean by have the libs wrongs? how do I change it? Thanks.

Comment: make sure, you use 32 bit libs for a 32 bit build, debug libs for a debug build, etc. mixing stuff there leads to exactly that kind of errors you get .

Comment: also, what rockingfresh said, update please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of OpenCV are you using, try running in both release and debug mode? it could be a bug. If I am not wrong, you should be on 2.3 or below? I used to have this error too. Use a newer and more stable version. 2.4.6 which contains tons of bugfixes. Using OpenCV2.3 is asking for problems. Try using the most latest and most stable release when possible.

On why it happens, you can find out over here:[OpenCV imread(filename) fails in debug mode when using release libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125817/opencv-imreadfilename-fails-in-debug-mode-when-using-release-libraries)

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Thanks! i am using version 2.3. So I have to download 2.4.6? Ok. this means I have to change all the include directories, etc after downloading the new version right?