# How do I resolve debug/release conflict after installing OpenCV under Anaconda

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

Tried to get started with OpenCV under Python today, although I have no experience with the former and very little experience with the latter. Since I am inexperienced, I followed a canned approach for the install, as detailed below.  Now I am trying to figure out if I need to install from source.

Started by downloading and installing Anaconda with Python 2.7.

Downloaded OpenCV 3.1.0 for Windows and moved the *cv2.pyd* file into *C:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages*.  I believe this means I installed a binary rather than from source.  Didn't tinker with any pathnames or environmental variables at this point.

Used Anaconda Launcher to start Spyder. `import cv2` ran in the Spyder console without complaint.  `print cv2.__version__` returned `3.1.0`, which I interpreted as a successful install.

Trouble began when I tried to do something.  `cv2.imread` is returning a `None` value.  The obvious explanation for this is that I am supplying the wrong filename but I don't think that's it. I ran `os.listdir('.')` and then `cv2.imread()` to eliminate this possibility.  The more sinister explanation is that I have mixed Debug and Release libraries (see this thread [OpenCV imread(filename) fails in debug mode when using release libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125817/opencv-imreadfilename-fails-in-debug-mode-when-using-release-libraries)).

My question is: how do I check if a release / debug conflict is indeed causing the problem?  I see some advice that references changing CMake parameters and rebuilding but since I just dropped a binary into a folder, that doesn't really relate to how I installed OpenCV. This brings me back to the question I started with: do I need to abandon the binary and reinstall from the source?  That is a daunting prospect for me.  I ran `cv2.getBuildInformation()` and it dumped a bunch of text on my console but I couldn't figure out what it meant.  It seemed to reference both Release and Debug modes.

EDIT: I'm running 64 bit Windows 7 Pro

Answer (score 0):

You might want to install OpenCV via [conda packages](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/) which downloads the binaries and does all the configuration for you. Open a command window (cmd.exe) and type:

```
conda update conda
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv
```

BUT, since you are starting I would recommend you to use Python 3. If you prefer not to do a fresh installation, you can create a conda environment with python 3.4 which runs independently and will not mesh up any of your installations:

```
conda create -n OpenCVenv python=3.4
```

To activate this environment you will need to run the following command every time you want to use opencv or install new packages

```
activate OpenCVenv
```

Once you have activated the environment you can install opencv3:

```
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv3
```

Notice that if you want to install the different packages such as Spyder you can do so:

```
conda install spyder
```

That's because Spyder is supported within Anaconda. For example you can install all the [packages included en Anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs)

```
conda install anaconda
```