# imread() still returns empty mat despite correct addressing in openCV 4.0.0

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am newbie to OPENCV.
Now I am trying to display an image using imread(), but imread() doesn't work(keep returning empty mat.) But when I try to draw lines, circles and so on by imread(), it works well.

So I thought there would be something wrong with addressing. And I tried everything I can but it still doesn't work. 
And I also have googled a lot of things to solve it, but I can't get any answer to this problem.

What should I do? Is there something wrong I have missed?

I currently use Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017, and openCV 4.0.0 alpha.

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#ifdef _DEBUG
#pragma comment(lib,"opencv_world400d.lib")
#else
#pragma comment(lib,"opencv_world400.lib")
#endif

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat image;
    image =imread("C:/Users/ymin/source/repos/Project1/Project1/BENZ.bmp",IMREAD_ANYCOLOR);
    if (image.empty()) 
    {std::cerr << "Could not open file" << std::endl; return (1);}
    imshow("image", image);
    waitKey();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the image isn't all black, and that it is a valid 
"bmp" format ?

Comment: Actually the first was just converted from png to bmp. I thought that image made something wrong. So I made another test image with paint tool basically installed in Windows. I just drew a black circle in white background, and saved it in 256pixels bmp format. but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [OpenCV documentation for `imread`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0-alpha/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56):

> If the image cannot be read (because of missing file, improper permissions, unsupported or invalid format), the function returns an empty matrix.

This indicates that the file is not there (maybe typo?), you don't have permission to read it, it is in a format not recognized by OpenCV, or it is corrupted.

Make sure the file is where you think it is, and that it is readable, and that OpenCV is compiled to support whatever format the file is in.

(Note that the file extension does not determine its format, you can take a JPEG file and rename it to have a `.bmp` extension, but it is still a JPEG file.)

Comment: What it means to have no permission? Do I have to set something about permission in the VS to make image files readable for openCV? Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: @추영민: No. If the file belongs to one user, the OS might not let a different user read the file. File permissions are properties of the file. If it is your file, and you can read it, then the program that you run should be allowed to read it as well. But it is something to take into account when there are multiple user accounts on a computer.

Comment: @추영민: Are you sure the forward slashes are OK under Windows? Files paths are typically written with backslashes there. I haven't used Windows in a long time, this might work nowadays, I don't know. Check it!

Comment: Well...I have only one account(of course it's mine) in my PC. So it seems that permission is not the problem. And I heard that forward slashes work well. but I changed all the forward slashes into backslash just in case. like this "C:\\Users\\ymin\\source\\repos\\Project1\\Project1\\BENZ.bmp" but result is same.

Comment: @추영민: So the last item on the list then is the format. Are you sure it actually is a BMP file, are you sure OpenCV comes with BMP support, and are you sure that the file can be read (open it in another program)?

Comment: I made an image with paint tool basically installed in Windows and save it as .bmp with 256-bits. And I checked it is opened in adobe photoshop.(I am not sure it is what you told). May be I need a break..so sad.

Comment: Thank you for your answering. I just uninstalled openCV 4.0.0 and installed again in version 3.4.1, then it worked well. Maybe there is something wrong with version 4.0.0 because it is alpha version yet. But I don't know exactly the reason why it didn't work. Anyway, I appreciate to your kindness :)

Comment: Maybe you are running your program [in debug mode while using release libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125817/opencv-imreadfilename-fails-in-debug-mode-when-using-release-libraries)